Triage review layout inconsistent with other review pages
Triage is the only review page without a filter, which is a bit odd but not something that bothers me.
The problem is that because the filter button is not there, "Your daily reviews" is aligned to the left, which is inconsistent.


On the review pages with filter button an empty div block (see code below) keeps the button to the left and reviews count to the right.
<div class="flex--item fl-grow1 js-review-filter-summary fs-italic fl1 ml8 mr12 v-truncate2"></div>

By adding this element before the flex--item containing "Your daily reviews" reviews count is aligned to the right bringing peace and harmony.
